# how to creat multiple empty dictionaries from names in a list in python?

Tags: python-2.7, list, loops, dictionary

I need to create multiple dictionaries from a list. if list is `['dic1','dict2']`, i want to creat two different dictionaries such as `sample_dic1` and `sample_dic2`.
if I don't use loops, I'll just type:

```py
sample_dic1=dict();sample_dic2=dict()
```

my question is how to do it in a loop from a name list.

I tried to put the list in loop while each value of the loop equal to `dict()`.
However, it does not assign the left-hand side to `dict()`.

```py
di_list=['dic1','dict2']
for (a) in di_list:
 'sample_{}'.format(a)=dict()
```

I also Tried this. it doesn't give any error. but doesn't work neigher

```py
temp=dict()
di_list=['dic1','dict2']
for (a) in di_list:
 temp[a]='sample_{}'.format(a)
 temp[a]=dict()
```

so I want to creat these two dictrionaries from `di_list` values. with `'sample_{}'.format(a)` I can creat my desired name, But binding it to `dict()` doesn't work. i.e,. `sample_{}'.format(a)=dict()`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain what the wider context is? Why does the variable name matter? Its just a name.

Comment: I have to create multiple dictionaries. since they are a lot, I want to create them automatically from a list rather than typing each one separately. with 'sample_{}'.format(a) I can create my desired name. However, when desired_name=dict(); I get:"SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

Comment: What are you creating them *for*? Why do they have to have a specific name binding? What about creating a list of dictionaries? Or a dictionary where the key is the name and the value is the dictionary you wanted to bind to that name? If you give more context (code, not words) - you'll get much better responses :)

Comment: post edited with the updated code

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing two things: variables names and values. Variable names do not have a real effective meaning and if you consistently change their names the program remains the same (in fact, it happens in most languages under the hood anyway).

Here is an option to refer to an arbitrary number of values by name, using a dictionary (name->value):

```
temp=dict()
di_list=['dic1','dict2']
for (a) in di_list:
    temp['sample_{}'.format(a)] = dict()
```

Now you can verify the values are in fact there:

```
assert temp['sample_dic1'] == {}  # True
assert temp['sample_dict2'] == {}  # True
```

Comment: No! what you did is renaming the keys of the dictionary 'temp' to 'sample_dic1' and 'sample_dict2' instead of what usually is 0, 1, 2 , etc,.  this answer is not the answer of the question. your answer is for the question of how to rename the keys of a dictionary to 'sample_dic1' and 'sample_dict2'.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but its a solution to the problem. While you can define variables arbitrarily, 99% chance you really don't want to. The code you present does not mention any reason to do something so hackish - so this is the way to go. You can refer to the dictionaries by their name as required. You're more than welcome to try your own thing though :)